# Is there any documentation about dask clusters connecting over ssh tunnels?

Tags: ssh, dask

I'm trying to setup a dask cluster on a system where only port 22 for SSH is open.  Is this feasible?  I've tried using port forwarding, and see some connections but then things fall apart.  Is there any documentation about this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a Dask client needs only one port to access the scheduler.  Typically this is port `8786`, but you should be able to map this with ssh port tunneling.  Dask itself has no particular documentation on how to use ssh port tunneling, but general documents on the internet should suffice.